# issue having radio button checked in session

Tags: php, session

i want radio buttons remain selected across all pagination. For taht

I have collected the checked value in pagination at the top of page.

But it is not working well.

What is wrong with this code ?

This is how i get selected value of radio button in session

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['answer'])) {
    $_SESSION['answer'] = $_POST['answer'];
}
```

This is my php code

```
<input type="radio"  name="answer" value="yes" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['answer'])=='yes') {echo "checked"; }?> />
<input type="radio"  name="answer" value="no" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['answer'])=='no') {echo "checked"; }?> />
<input type="radio"  name="answer" value="yes1" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['answer'])=='yes1') {echo "checked"; }?> />
<input type="radio"  name="answer" value="yes2" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['answer'])=='yes2') {echo "checked"; }?> />
```

It gives me error(notice) like answer is undefined index.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP hasn't read the manual page for [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/function.isset.php)

Answer (score 3):

isset() returns true or false.  Your if statement should be, for example:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['answer']) && $_SESSION['answer'] == 'yes')
```

Comment: Thank you bozdoz for replay.But it is also not working.giving same error.answer is undefined index.

Comment: You may have other problems in your code then.  Check out the demo: http://ideone.com/Yi4FKH

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
$values = array('yes', 'no', 'yes1', 'yes2');
foreach ( $values as $value ) {
  $checked = isset($_SESSION['answer']) && $_SESSION['answer'] == $value ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
  echo '<input type="radio"  name="answer" value="' . $value . '" ' . $checked . '/>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="radio"  name="answer" value="yes" <?php if($_SESSION['answer']=='yes') { ?> checked="checked" <?php }?> />
<input type="radio"  name="answer" value="no"  <?php if($_SESSION['answer']=='no') { ?> checked="checked" <?php }?> />
<input type="radio"  name="answer" value="yes1" <?php if($_SESSION['answer']=='yes1') { ?> checked="checked" <?php }?> />
<input type="radio"  name="answer" value="yes2" <?php if($_SESSION['answer']=='yes2') { ?> checked="checked" <?php }?> />

please use this html
```

Comment: Thanks Ankit..I ll try it and let u know.

Comment: ok punam123 , please let me know if have any issue

Comment: No ankit. giving same error.I think my code  having some issues

Comment: please tell me the error

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: answer in D:\wamp\www\sampleTest\test.php on line 64

Comment: no that should not be due this code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37857/discussion-between-ankit-agrawal-and-punam123)